# How to sortorder the category search results with our product attribute in magento2

Tags: magento2

How to sortorder the category search results with our product attribute not by relavance in magento2 or with both relavance and our product attribute

Comment: It is a bit unclear what you are trying to ask.  We will need to see the code on your end to make any sense of this.

Answer (score 0):

```
          public function setListOrders()
{
    $category = $this->catalogLayer->getCurrentCategory();
    /* @var $category \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category */
    $availableOrders = $category->getAvailableSortByOptions();
    unset($availableOrders['position']);
    $availableOrders['relevance'] = __('Relevance');

    $this->getListBlock()->setAvailableOrders(
        $availableOrders
    )->setDefaultDirection(
        'desc'
    )->setDefaultSortBy(
        'relevance'
    );
enter code here
    return $this;
}
```